# In jBpm, how to get all transitions that has been taken in a flow/process?

Tags: java, jbpm

Is it possible in jboss jBpm to fetch all transitions that has been taken during one process execution?

---

The use case is: We would like to now all nodes, tasknodes, ... that '*users*' has been through and which *transition* they took.

This to show a list of task instances that have been finished previously from the current active token/node till the *start* task.

Some *not working ideas* already explored:

- Take the active tokens and their corresponding node and travel up the transitions through the arriving transitions. This does not work as multiple transitions can be incoming, so we do not know which transition has been taken.

Probably I should investigate the JBPM_LOG table, but I didn't found a proper way (API) to query this. Any suggestions to any online documentation would also be welcome.

Note: We are using *jBpm version:3.3.1*

Comment: Can you post (as answer or as comment) your solution to the problem please?

Comment: @Vangar, I'll post it once i have written it, probably somewhere next week.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use jbpm_log table if you need to get transitions. To get all proceeded nodes you only need jbpm_taskInstance table.
We use HQL to get all user's transition in process. I had a task about "to know wich transition user choosed for given taskInstance". It's not a obvious way to do such thing, but i cannot invent something more clear. In my case it's not a very common action in app so it's realized in "fastest-to-code-it" way. Obviously 3 queries for single task instance in your case is not a good choose.
The only docs i needed were: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/javadoc/ for help on Jbpm classes and packages and discriminator's class list: jbpm-jpdl.jar/org.jbpm.logging.log/ProcessLog.hbm.xml  (has desciption about jbpm objects - DB table mapping)
This is the method's code. CriteriaSQL is our CriteriaParams wrapper.
As i said it isn't best example but I also have saved plain sql queries for oracle DB if you needs it.

```
    private String getTaskTransition(LFTaskInstance instance) {     
        CriteriaSQL csql = new CriteriaSQL(new CriteriaParams());


        String query = "SELECT l " +
            " FROM org.jbpm.taskmgmt.log.TaskCreateLog l " +
            " WHERE l.taskInstance = " + instance.getId();      

        Query c =((HibernateSession)em).getHibernateSession().createQuery(csql.getQueryString(query));
        TaskCreateLog logEntry  = (TaskCreateLog) c.uniqueResult(); 
        int index = logEntry.getIndex();
        Long token = logEntry.getToken().getId();

        //Find bottom log index of transition which greater then log index of current instance creation
        String subQuery = "SELECT min(jbpmLog.index) " + 
                " FROM org.jbpm.graph.log.TransitionLog as jbpmLog " +
                " where jbpmLog.token = trLog.token AND " + //reference to query below
                        " jbpmLog.index > " + index; 

        //Find transition name from its Definition by log index of made transition
        query = " SELECT trans.name FROM org.jbpm.graph.def.Transition as trans " +
                " WHERE trans.id = " +
        " (SELECT min(transition.id) " +
        " FROM org.jbpm.graph.log.TransitionLog trLog " +
        " WHERE trLog.token = " + token + 
        "       and trLog.index = (" + subQuery + "))";

        c =((HibernateSession)em).getHibernateSession().createQuery(csql.getQueryString(query));
        return (String) c.uniqueResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Processes that have already been completed or partially processed?  If not, then you could put an action handler on every exit transition that records the name of the transition by looking for it in the current token.

Comment: It's for a new system, so yes this could be done,but I still rather not have the constraint of having to design all flows and future flows with a specific action handler. Similarly, I could log this in my application service method. My preferred way is still using the standard jbpm functionalities. But yes, your solution should work fine.

Comment: I have a full JBPM database here from a production site and it appears that the only way would be to sift through the log.  However, in my JBPM implementation I used JBPM as a means to do the workflow grunt work, while I stored all my data regarding the workflow in my own tables and it has worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

We use sql select like this (logging into table JBPM_LOG must be enabled in file jbpm.cfg.xml):

```
select distinct *
  from (select level,
               l.date_,
               pd1.name_ p1,
               n1.name_ n1,
               pd2.name_ p2,
               n2.name_ n2
          from juser.jbpm_log               l,
               juser.jbpm_node              n1,
               juser.jbpm_node              n2,
               juser.jbpm_processdefinition pd1,
               juser.jbpm_processdefinition pd2,
               juser.jbpm_token             t,
               juser.jbpm_processinstance   pi,
               juser.jbpm_token             t2
         where l.class_ = 'T'
           and n1.id_ = l.sourcenode_
           and n2.id_ = l.destinationnode_
           and n1.processdefinition_ = pd1.id_
           and n2.processdefinition_ = pd2.id_
           and t.id_ = l.token_
           and t.processinstance_ = pi.id_
           and pi.superprocesstoken_ = t2.id_
        connect by prior pi.id_ = t2.processinstance_
         start with pi.id_ =
                    (select id_
                       from (select pi.id_
                               from juser.jbpm_processinstance pi,
                                    juser.jbpm_token           t
                              where pi.superprocesstoken_ = t.id_
                             connect by prior t.processinstance_ = pi.id_
                              start with pi.id_ = <<<ID_OF_PROCESSINSTANCE>>>
                              order by pi.id_)
                      where rownum = 1)
         order by l.date_)
 order by date_;
```

This uses connect by prior - I don't know if this work on anything other than oracle.